# Find a `?` in a Pandas DataFrame and view only the rows and columns (location of `?`)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

#### Situation

- Take in a `.csv` file
- Replace all non-ascii characters with a `?`
- Find row and columns that have a `?` and display their location (in a df or list)

#### Sample Code

```
df = pd.read_csv('../test.csv', sep='|', skiprows=1)
find_non_ascii = df.select_dtypes(object)
df[find_non_ascii.columns] = find_non_ascii.apply(lambda x: x.str.encode("ascii", "replace").str.decode("ascii")
)
df2 = df[find_non_ascii.columns]
quest = '\\?'
lster = []
try:
    for col in cols:
        df3 = df2.loc[df2[f'{col}'].str.contains(quest, na=False)]
        if df3.items():
            lster.append(df3)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print(lster)
```

#### Output

````
[    NAME EARPHONES MODEL_NUMBER   ID  CAR
 0  d?fgh      ?g?s          s-s  d?d  asd,
     NAME EARPHONES MODEL_NUMBER   ID  CAR
 0  d?fgh      ?g?s          s-s  d?d  asd
 1    dfg        A?          NaN   af    a,
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [NAME, EARPHONES, MODEL_NUMBER, ID, CAR]
 Index: [],
     NAME EARPHONES MODEL_NUMBER   ID  CAR
 0  d?fgh      ?g?s          s-s  d?d  asd,
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [NAME, EARPHONES, MODEL_NUMBER, ID, CAR]
 Index: []]```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask (True/False) for each row using `df.apply`, where `df` is most likely `df2` in your situation but I left it as `df` for simplicity.

```
df['mask'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(x[col].__contains__('?') for col in df.columns), axis = 1)
```

You can then filter the dataframe using this mask to show only the rows where the mask is `True` (the row contains any `'?'`).

```
df.loc[df['mask']]
```

And to remove the mask column showing in the result

```
df.loc[df['mask'],df.columns[:-1]]
```